# How to create real-time changes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, visualizer

So I wrote a pretty basic code. I'm a real noob. Started JavaScript 3 days back. I want the sorting process to be visualized while the sorting is going on. But when the SORT button is clicked after a while the sorted array is show. But what I want is to show the changes happening to the array in real-time.
Please help me out.

```
var array = [];
container_content= "";
for (var i=0; i < 50; i++) {
    array.push(Math.random() *500)
} 

container_content = "";

function myFunction(element) {
    container_content += '<div class="array-bar"></div>';
}
array.forEach(myFunction);
$(".container").html(container_content);

function another(element, index){
    element.style.height = array[index]
}
$( "div" ).each( function( index, element ){
    $( this ).css('height', array[index]);
});

$('button').click(function(){
    var i, j, temp;
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++)
        {
            if( array[j] > array[j+1])
            {
                // swap the elements
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = temp;
            } 
        }
            $( "div" ).each( function( index, element ){
            $( this ).css('height', array[index]);
            });

    }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took what you were trying to do and broke it  down into 4 basic functions (1 main function and 3 helper functions).

`runSort` is the main function that uses all the other helper functions to do everything.

`makeArrayAndUnsyncedBars` generates your random array and basic divs that you'll use as green "bars", but it doesn't set the heights of these divs according to the values in the array.

`syncArrayToBars` sets the heights of these "bar" divs according to the values in the array

`sortUntilNextSwap` sorts the array until either a swap occurs or the sort completes. this function returns `false` if it made a swap (meaning that it's still working its way through the array) or `true` otherwise.

```js
var FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 50;

var sortInterval = null;
function runSort() {
  clearInterval(sortInterval);

  makeArrayAndUnsyncedBars(50);
  syncArrayToBars();

  sortInterval = setInterval(function() {
    var finishedSorting = sortUntilNextSwap();
    syncArrayToBars();

    if (finishedSorting) clearInterval(sortInterval);
  }, Math.round(1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND));
}

var array = [];
function makeArrayAndUnsyncedBars(numberOfValues) {
  var htmlToAdd = "";
  array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++) {
    htmlToAdd += "<div class=\"bar\"></div>";
    array.push(rando(150));
  }
  $("#bars").html(htmlToAdd);
}

function syncArrayToBars() {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) $(".bar").eq(i).css({
    height: array[i] + "px"
  });
}

var i, j, temp;
function sortUntilNextSwap() {
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
      if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
        // swap the elements
        temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[j + 1];
        array[j + 1] = temp;
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 5px;
  background: #5aedab;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<div id="bars"></div>
<button onclick="runSort();">Run sort</button>
```

**EDIT:** I should mention that I used [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js) for the randomness out of habit, but it's not super necessary here given that you use `Math.random()` very little anyway. Take it out or leave it in according to your preference.